# Import many users into SimpleMembershipProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I am using MVC4+SimpleMemebershipProvider and have my own profile table. In my project I have functionality to import users into my application. Everything is fine until number of importing users is quite small (up to 100), but for example importing 1000 take ages. To be precised I am trying to synchronize company user database with my own (it is not always an Active Directory) and I am using CSV file to be flexible.

I see following solutions:

1. Extend membership provider (probably by copy it code, because some functions are private) to add functionality of "bulk insert"
2. Write my own membership provider

So my questions are: did somebody did something like this before? Do I have other alternatives?

p.s. I founded Code First Membership Provider, but this solution does not support methods like: reset password, registration with confirmation, etc.

Comment: Can you profile it to determine where the actual bottleneck is?  You have a number of options for migrating data, including just inserting it directly into the database and not going through the application.

Comment: The bottelneck is: SimpleMemebershipProvider for every user open connection make one insert, close connection. I was thinking about inserting data directly, but I don't feel good with such solution.